# Tensorflow saver restore. Variable values seem to have changed.

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm running training in tensorflow to create a trained model which I save to a checkpoint with

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=1)
saver.save(sess, checkpointPath, global_step=global_step+1000)
```

Later I build the same model and initialise it with

```
ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(checkpointDir)    
saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=1)
saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
```

When I run with this restored network for a few more steps I get quite different results to if I had continued with the original network. I would expect them to be the same. I'm trying to work out why.

Does anybody have any suggestions? I believe I am saving all variables (though maybe not).

I'd like to set up a test that asserts that all of the variables are the same in the restored model as they were in the saved model but can't work out how to do this. Does anybody have a code fragment to show this?

I would like to use my saved model to load up trained predictor.

Comment: One thing that I've done for a similar purpose, but just on one variable, as a sanity check, is to first 'run' that variable into a numpy array and dump that array into a CSV prior to saving the model, then do the same in the restored model and compare the content. That all matched one-to-ne for every single element, so that gave me some comfort for the others. I suppose if you want to do it for ALL variables, you could just do something like an average of each variable and to compare those?

Comment: That sounds useful. I shall do this to investigate further.

Comment: Why are you doing `global_step=global_step+1000`? You can print the checkpoint path to see if the one you restored from is same with the one you has save to.